# SerilLog not logging in web application

Tags: logging, web, class-library, serilog

On my WebUI project startUp.cs class i have

```
        public Startup()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                   .WriteTo.Console()
                   .CreateLogger();
    }
```

and in my class library project sample.cs class i am calling

```
                Log.Logger.Information("This will be written to the rolling file set");
```

the both using serilog and class library has webUI reference
but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: i have already tried it in a sample wpf project and it works fine, it logs to console and file but not in class library/web app

Comment: Just a note, you can use `Log.Information()` as a shortcut version of `Log.Logger.Information()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the web app is running under IIS, you won't get output via the console. It's also likely that the app pool account IIS is using won't have access to many local paths. The trick here is usually finding a local path with valid permissions.

You can get additional diagnostics from Serilog's internal log: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics